# Can I program AVR Microcontrollers using Arduino Development board with AVR Studio?

Tags: arduino-uno, avr, atmel-studio

I know and I can program any AVR microcontroller with Arduino IDE and Arduino Uno board. Can I use Arduino board with AVR Studio? Or I have to buy an AVR Development board?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Atmel Studio to write code for the MCU(s) on the Arduino boards. If the IDE itself does not support *uploading* the code to the Arduino then it is still possible to use AVRDUDE or BOSSA to upload it via the command line.

Comment: Using Atmel Studio, could he program via ISP (SPI)? I have never tried it as I have a Dragon and STK500.

Comment: I'm sure he could. But the Arduino likely already has a perfectly good bootloader on it for serial uploading.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Then what happens If wanted to upload code from Atmel Studio while Arduino has it's own bootloader loaded on the MCU? Does that matter?

Comment: @Zgrkpnr__: All the Arduino bootloader does is allow serial programming instead of requiring ISP. It does not affect the development environment in any other way.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams You are giving answers as If you read my mind.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [Arduino plugin](http://www.visualmicro.com/) available for AVR Studio, which allows you to upload sketches to an Arduino, just like you would with the Arduino IDE. I think this also enables you to upload plain C/C++ files created with the standard AVR tools.

Alternatively, if you have an AVR ISP programmer, you can use this to upload compiled C/C++ to the Arduino from AVR studio without needing the Arduino plugin.